# Book recommendation on PDE

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

I want to read some book about **PDE**, especially  about **parabolic** differential equations.

I know a little basic conception and theorem of PDE,and it's very basic and little.So, I hope it is **not too hard**. If it's **self-contain**,it's best .

And I am reading a paper of geometrical analysis.So, I hope it's a PDE book **tend to geometry**.

Besides, I really love Evans' book, but I feel it is  too many pages. I want one is **thin**.

Maybe,there are too many requirements.Thanks for any useful recommendation.

Comment: Um... Is Evan's book old?

Comment: It is mentioned in the preface of Evan's book, **1997**! Is it not that much old as you say! Just 17 years from 2015! :)

Comment: @JohnMa  H.R.    I have edit it,

Comment: You might try [this one](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=gsmseries&ikey=GSM-12) and [this one](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=20&arg1=gsmseries&ikey=GSM-96).

Comment: @JohnMa Thanks,

Comment: @user99914, both links come up to an AMS preorder page; what are the authors, titles, nr. pages ("I want one is thin") please ?